# For Loop in Shiny Server: How to Not Overwrite Values with Each ActionButton Press?

Tags: for-loop, shiny, wordcloud2

I am trying to create an app in which part of the UI displays a wordcloud generated by words/strings inputted by the user. To do this, I pass the input to a for loop which is supposed to then store every input in an empty vector with ever press of the action button. However, I am encountering a couple problems, though: one in that no word cloud is displaying, with no error indicated, and another in that the for loop will just overwrite the vector each time the button is pressed, such that it always only has one word in it instead of gradually adding more words. I figured the lack of display is because there is only one word, and it seems like wordcloud needs at least two words to print anything: so how can I get the for loop to work as intended with Shiny?

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(wordcloud2)



ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Strings Sim"),

 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  textInput("string.input", "Create a string:", placeholder = "string <-"),
  actionButton("go1", "GO!")
),

  mainPanel(
   textOutput("dummy"),
   wordcloud2Output("the.cloud")
  )


)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


 observeEvent(input$go1, {

   high.strung <- as.vector(input$string.input)
   empty.words <- NULL

for (i in high.strung) {
  empty.words <- c(empty.words, i)
}

word.vector <-matrix(empty.words, nrow = length(empty.words),ncol=1)

num.vector <- matrix(sample(1000), nrow=length(empty.words),ncol=1)

prelim <- cbind(word.vector, num.vector)

prelim.data <- as.data.frame(prelim)

prelim.data$V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(prelim.data$V2))

 output$the.cloud <- renderWordcloud2(
  wordcloud2(prelim.data)
   )

print(empty.words)
  })
  }

     shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The operation works as intended when I run it without Shiny code; I basically just use a string in place of the input, run through the for loop a few times to generate the dataframe to be used by word cloud, and get something like the attached picture, which is what I am after:[image: Example Output]

Functional code without Shiny:

```
 empty.words <- NULL

 #Rerun below here to populate vector with more words and regenerate wordcloud

 high.strung <- as.vector("gumbo")

 for (i in high.strung) {
   empty.words <- c(empty.words, i)
   return(empty.words)
 }

 word.vector <-matrix(empty.words, nrow = length(empty.words),ncol=1)

 num.vector <- matrix(sample(1000), nrow=length(empty.words),ncol=1)

 prelim <- cbind(word.vector, num.vector)

 prelim.data <- as.data.frame(prelim)

 prelim.data$V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(prelim.data$V2))

 str(prelim.data)

 wordcloud2(prelim.data)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: More pictures of the desired output using the non-Shiny code. (I editted the dataframe output to overlay the wordcloud just to show the cloud and frame in one picture, i.e. don't need them to display in that way). With each press of the button, the inputted word(s) should be added to the dataframe that builds the cloud, gradually making it larger.The random number vector which determines the size doesn't have to stay the same with each press, but each inputted word should be preserved in a vector. [image: Ex2] [image: Ex3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is missing reactivity. You can read about that concept [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). You can input strings and as soon as at least two words are in the dataframe the wordcloud is rendered. If you don't want multi-word strings to be split just take out the `str_split()` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(wordcloud2)



ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Strings Sim"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("string.input", "Create a string:", placeholder = "string <-"),
      actionButton("go1", "GO!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("dummy"),
      wordcloud2Output("the.cloud")
    )


  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(high.strung = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$go1, {
    rv$high.strung <- c(rv$high.strung,str_split(c(input$string.input), pattern = " ") %>% unlist)
  })

  prelim.data <- reactive({
    prelim <- data.frame(
      word.vector = rv$high.strung, 
      num.vector = sample(1000, length(rv$high.strung), replace = TRUE)
    )
  })

  output$the.cloud <- renderWordcloud2(
    if (length(rv$high.strung) > 0)
      wordcloud2(prelim.data())
  )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: This is close to what I need. Ideally, I wanted it so that for every word or string inputted into the textInput and submitted with the action button, it is stored in a vector which is then passed to a data frame to be used by wordcloud2. So if the user put in "stumps" and hit the action button, that is passed to an empty vector and stored there, with a random value assigned to it in the other vector which it gets paired with in the data frame. Then if the user puts in "tree" and submits,  that would be the second element in the vector, second row in the data frame.

Comment: I added a couple more pictures to better show what I would ideally like to happen. The random number portion (which determines the size of the word in the cloud) doesn't have to be held constant - but I would like every inputted word to be passed to and stored in a vector with the press of the action button which can then be used to build an expanding cloud. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Code example edited so that multiple inputs are now concatenated.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was after! Thank you so much for the help! I am still trying to really wrap my head around reactivity in general, and this spared me days worth of more headscratching trying to understand which part needed to be made reactive.